# Why do some Bible versions have "new" in Genesis 27:28 but others do not?

Tags: genesis

> "Therefore may God give you

> Of the dew of heaven,

> Of the fatness of the earth,

> And plenty of grain and wine." Genesis 27:28 NKJB.

> "May God give you of heaven's dew and of earth's richness- an abundance of grain  and new wine." Genesis 27:28 NIV.

"new wine" in NIV; Berean Study Bible; NASB 1977.

"wine" [without the "new"] in NKJB; ESV; Aramaic Bible.

Comment: The reason some translations have "new wine" is because in the cognate languages "Tiros" means unfermented wine, and in some "fresh wine". See HALOT. Its the scholarly interpretation of תירוש, not all translations feel the need to reflect that research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the word used (תִּירֹושׁ) in Gen. 27:28 isn't the typical word for wine (יַ֫יִן) that is in Gen. 27:25. Looking at the lexicons, there is a dispute over the meaning of תִּירֹושׁ, whether it means *new wine* or whether it is just an archaic word for *wine.*  However, it does occur 38 times in 38 verses of the Tanakh. Although it is less than the 141 times יַיִן is used, 38 times is significant for an archaic word and makes one think there was a purpose in it's usage.

> תִּירוֹשׁ n.m. Ju 9:13 *must, fresh or new wine*
> --
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). *Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon* (p. 440). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

> תִּירוֹשׁ & תִּירשׁ m. *must, new wine* (so called, because in intoxicating, it takes possession of the brain, from the root יָרַשׁ, compare Syr. ܡܶܙܪܺܝܬܐܳ id.), Gen. 27:28. אֶרֶץ דָּגָן וְתִירוֹשׁ a land abounding in corn and new wine, Deut. 33:28; 2 Ki. 18:32; Isa. 36:17. Used of the juice of grapes, Is. 65:1.
> --
> Gesenius, W., & Tregelles, S. P. (2003). *Gesenius’ Hebrew and Chaldee lexicon to the Old Testament Scriptures* (p. 863). Bellingham, WA: Logos Bible Software.

> תִּירוֹשׁ, תִּירֹשׁ: sf. תִּירוֹשְׁךָ: (archaic word for) *wine* (in ritual & poetic ctxts.) Gn 27:28.
> --
> Holladay, W. L., & Köhler, L. (2000). *A concise Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament* (p. 389). Leiden: Brill.

Answer (score 1):

The operative word is תִּירוֹשׁ H8492 tirosh, [Strong's](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/8492.htm) Exhaustive Concordance:

> fresh grape-juice (as just squeezed out); by implication (rarely) fermented wine

NASB Translation:
fresh wine (1), grapes (1), new wine (33), wine (3).

In the strict sense, it means new wine. By extension, sometimes it is interpreted as fermented wine.

Genesis 27:28
New International Version:

> May God give you heaven’s dew and earth’s richness— an abundance of grain and **new wine**.

NIV interpreted the word strictly as "new wine".

New King James Version:

> Therefore may God give you Of the dew of heaven, Of the fatness of the earth, And plenty of grain and **wine**.

NKJV interpreted it inclusively as "wine" meaning new wine and fermented old wine.

At https://biblehub.com/parallel/genesis/27-28.htm, 19 versions use "new wine" and 22 uses just "wine".

Why do some Bible versions have "new" in Genesis 27:28 but others do not?

That's a matter of interpretation depending on the translators.